# Wordpress comments getting auto approved despite moderation settings

Tags: wordpress, comments

I am stuck with this one - my wordpress/wooCommerce site is getting flogged by spammers.

The moderation settings in settings->discussion are set as follows...

[image: My wordpress comment settings]

None of these settings seem to have any effect. I get no emails and the comments are just approved, so the spammers are killing me.

I also have akismet installed - it even mentions it has 'flagged the comments as spam' but doesn't move them to the spam folder.

The only conclusion I can make is something else is taking over the normal functionality.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, as suspected this was a plugin. It was called 'honeypot' which is meant to be a nice easy 'set and forget' plugin that stops spam.

Just for those wordpress users suffering from spam attacks - I found a superior way to block comment spam.

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -
//      Spam Comments Checker
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function get_the_user_ip() {
    if ( ! empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] ) ) {

    //check ip from share internet
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif ( ! empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] ) ) {

    //to check ip is pass from proxy
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return apply_filters( 'dm_get_ip', $ip );
}

if( function_exists( 'add_action' ) ) {
    add_action( 'preprocess_comment', function ($commentdata) {
        $userIdesntity = md5( get_the_user_ip().time() );
        if( !isset( $_POST['is_valid_comment'] ) && trim( $_POST['is_valid_comment'] )== $userIdesntity ) {
            die( 'Comment Spam Detected' );
        }
        return $commentdata;
    }); 
};

//load js
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() { 
    //add floating widget script
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'comment-spam-fix',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/comment-spam-fix.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
});
```

Here is the jQuery...

```
var cForm = jQuery('.comment-form');

cForm.find('input[type=submit]').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: cForm.attr('action') + '?' + cForm.serialize() + '&is_valid_comment=',
        method: 'post'
    }).done(function( data ) {
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert( "error" );
    });
});
```

And the icing on the cake is this little snippet you can add to your .htaccess file. Even if you block the comments, the spammers are still making your server do work. This fix will also be jetpack comment safe for those who use it.

Don't even make your server generate a 404 page for them...

Direct them to a junk webpage...

```
# BEGIN Anti Comment Spam
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)wp-comments-post\.php*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^(.*)yourwebsite\.com\.* 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://jetpack\.wordpress\.com/jetpack-comment/ [OR]
RewriteRule (.*) http://98jmtyxj2z9r3rhj920.com.ar/$ [R=301,L]
# END Anti Comment Spam
```

Let me know if this helps you :)